# Why the radius of curvature of a curve is independent of the choice of the coordinate axes.

Tags: calculus

The radius of curvature of a curve $y=f(x)$ is given by $\rho=\frac{(1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}$.
I know this formula.Its derivation is also given in the book and i understood that.But i did not understand the following concept.
Since the value of $\rho$ is independent of the choice of the coordinate axes,so interchanging $x$ and $y$,the $\rho$ is also given by $\rho=\frac{(1+(\frac{dx}{dy})^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}}$.

---

I did not understand why the radius of curvature does not depend upon the interchange of coordinate axes.Please help.

Comment: Would change of axis change relative distance between two points

Comment: Radius of curvature at a point can be also defined as the radius of circle with center at the intersection of two infinitesimally closed normals along a curve at a specific point and circle should be including that point. I recommend try deriving radius of curvature using this definition. It will be fun. 
And on the question part, I will just put another question, why would that radius change?

Comment: It's a geometric quantity of the curve when seen as an embedded curve in the two plane. Therefore it does not (actually, must not) depend on it's representation. Of course you do not see this from the definition you have cited, but the one suggested from Mann allows you to see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book gives you a true statement but the last formula is questionable.

Curves' curvature is like talking about radius of a  circle. With any coordinate transformation, the circle is still the same circle and so its radius.

However, interchanging x, y in the formula, may change sign if you use the formula.

Assuming you can parametrize the curve $x=x(t), y=y(t)$
$$\rho=\frac{(1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}=\frac{((x')^2+(y')^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{y''x'-x''y'}$$

So interchanging x and y will give you the same absolute value but with different sign.